# Do/can browsers use diffs in http requests?

Tags: http, browser, diff

I know browsers already use caching and gzipping to lessen the burden, but why not diffs?

Say I have a 30k+ line javascript file and I change a single character in it. Even gzipped, the browser is going to have to download the whole thing again.. Wouldn't it be better to use diffing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that is maybe a good idea for your senario but HTTP is not designed for that. HTTP is designed for serving documents over the internet.

HTTP has the option to say here is your content wich just small differances download the document if you like but you don't need that. This the the work of the [E-Tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) with its weak option (`W/...`).

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice, but fundamentally difficult/impossible.

diff presumes that you're working with the same (or almost-the-same) original copy on both sides. How would you check if the cached copy in the browser is sufficiently similar that a diff could apply cleanly?

Comment: Well my point is that it would be more that the server could do. Maybe the file is completely different - no diff. Maybe it's one character difference - diff.

Comment: And how do you generate that diff? What if you're trying to serve up v3.14, but the browser has v2.718 cached?

Comment: I mean the server would generate the diff... Actually, I see what you're saying: the server would also have to know which version the browser has.